# Intersection Observer: Remove/ Add classes based on <header> and <footer> viewport position

Tags: javascript, scroll, sticky, sticky-footer, intersection-observer

I have a question relating to the [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver).

As you can see in [my code](https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/ZEYXPOR), when you scroll down to the `<footer>` the `.product-photo` **(T-Shirt)** stays fixed and I'm not sure how to properly add the `.absolute` class to make it positioned bottom to it's container.

> ***Note:*** I'm aware of css's `position: sticky` but it won't work for this particular case

**My Goal:** Make the T-Shirt image...

☑ `static` when the header is in view
☑ `fixed` when the header is not in view
☐ `absolute` when the footer is in view

I have everything working except the `absolute` class

[image]

```js
const photo = document.querySelector(".product-photo");
const header = document.querySelector("header");

const sectionOptions = {
 root: null
};

const sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, sectionObserver) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      photo.classList.add("fixed");
    } 
  else {
      photo.classList.remove("fixed");
    }
  });
}, sectionOptions);


sectionObserver.observe(header);
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: roboto; }

header, footer { background: black; color: white; padding: 2rem; }
footer { height: 100vh; }
main { background: white; padding: 1rem; }
section { margin: 2rem 0; }
h1, h2 { margin: 0 0 1rem; font-size: 2rem; }
p { margin: 0 0 2rem; font-size: 1.2rem; line-height: 1.4; }
img { max-width: 100%; }

/* styles
****************************************/
.announcement { background: #f2f2f2; font-size: 2rem; padding: 2rem; text-align: center; border: 3px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.2); margin-top: 0; }
.product { height: 100%; display: flex; justify-items: space-between; position: relative; }
.product-photo { width: 50%; }
.product-description { width: 50%; }
.recommended-products { display: flex; }

/* Sticky Classes */
.product-photo.fixed img { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; }
.product-photo.absolute img { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 50%; }

/* .fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; } */




/* Mobile */
@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 768px) { 
 .product { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
 .product-photo { width: 100%; }
 .product-description { width: 100%; }
}
  
/* Tablet */
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) { 
 
    
}
  
/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 1025px) { 
 
    
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
 
 <!-- Product -->
 <section class="product">
  <figure class="product-photo">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0078/6825/2273/products/SSCrew_TrueBlack_Front_1950x.png" alt="Black T-Shirt">
  </figure>
  <article class="product-description">
   <h1>Black T-Shirt</h1>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
  </article>
 </section>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `footer` to the observer and add/remove `fixed` and `absolute` classes by testing `isIntersecting` of the header/footer which you can get in your case by using `entry.target.tagName`:

```
const header = document.querySelector("header");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");

const sectionOptions = {
    root: null
};

const sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, sectionObserver) {
  const headerEntry = entries.find(entry => entry.target.tagName === 'HEADER');
  const footerEntry = entries.find(entry => entry.target.tagName === 'FOOTER');
  if (headerEntry && headerEntry.isIntersecting) {
    photo.classList.remove("fixed");
  } else if(footerEntry && footerEntry.isIntersecting) {
    photo.classList.remove("fixed");
    photo.classList.add("absolute");
  } else {
    photo.classList.add("fixed");
    photo.classList.remove("absolute");
  }
}, sectionOptions);


sectionObserver.observe(header);
sectionObserver.observe(footer);
```

**Live example:**

```js
const photo = document.querySelector(".product-photo");
const header = document.querySelector("header");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");

const sectionOptions = {
 root: null
};

const sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, sectionObserver) {
  const headerEntry = entries.find(entry => entry.target.tagName === 'HEADER');
  const footerEntry = entries.find(entry => entry.target.tagName === 'FOOTER');
  if (headerEntry && headerEntry.isIntersecting) {
    photo.classList.remove("fixed");
  } else if(footerEntry && footerEntry.isIntersecting) {
    photo.classList.remove("fixed");
    photo.classList.add("absolute");
  } else {
    photo.classList.add("fixed");
    photo.classList.remove("absolute");
  }
}, sectionOptions);


sectionObserver.observe(header);
sectionObserver.observe(footer);
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: roboto; }

header, footer { background: black; color: white; padding: 2rem; }
footer { height: 100vh; }
main { background: white; padding: 1rem; }
section { margin: 2rem 0; }
h1, h2 { margin: 0 0 1rem; font-size: 2rem; }
p { margin: 0 0 2rem; font-size: 1.2rem; line-height: 1.4; }
img { max-width: 100%; }

/* styles
****************************************/
.announcement { background: #f2f2f2; font-size: 2rem; padding: 2rem; text-align: center; border: 3px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.2); margin-top: 0; }
.product { height: 100%; display: flex; justify-items: space-between; position: relative; }
.product-photo { width: 50%; }
.product-description { width: 50%; }
.recommended-products { display: flex; }

/* Sticky Classes */
.product-photo.fixed img { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; }
.product-photo.absolute img { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 50%; }

/* .fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; } */




/* Mobile */
@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 768px) { 
 .product { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
 .product-photo { width: 100%; }
 .product-description { width: 100%; }
}
  
/* Tablet */
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) { 
 
    
}
  
/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 1025px) { 
 
    
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
 
 <!-- Product -->
 <section class="product">
  <figure class="product-photo">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0078/6825/2273/products/SSCrew_TrueBlack_Front_1950x.png" alt="Black T-Shirt">
  </figure>
  <article class="product-description">
   <h1>Black T-Shirt</h1>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
   <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
  </article>
 </section>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution! But how would I add the class `absolute` and remove the class `fixed` to the `.product-photo` if the footer isIntersecting?

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what I was trying to do :)